# Html5 Background not working (in other html it does)

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>WEB DESIGN</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img id="circle" src="circle.png" alt="circle"/>
        <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
                <a href="#">
                <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 39%;">Home</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 46%;">About</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 53%;">Contact</li>
                </a>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><img id="src" style="margin-right: 6%" src="src.png" /></a>
        <img id="ham" src="ham.png" style="margin-right: 2%" alt="ham"/>
        <img id="smpline" src="smpline.png" style="margin-left: 5%;" alt="smpline"/>
        <div class="welcome">
            <p id="big">Web Design</p>
            <p id="sml">
                Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris <br />
                condimentum , ut fermentum massa justo sit amet <br />
                erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit <br />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

        <img id="lowerfoto" src="lower.png" alt="lower"/>
        <div class="head">
            <img id="fteweit" src="fterwit.png" alt="white"/>
            <ul class="head">
                <li id="head" style="margin-left: 10%;">FOLLOW US</li>
                <li id="head" style="margin-left: 30%;">GET TO KNOW US</li>
                <li id="head" style="margin-left: 50%;">LOCATIONS</li>
                <li id="head" style="margin-left: 70%;">OUR MISSION</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="under">
                <li class="under" style="margin-left: 10%;">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">Twitter</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">Faceboook</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">Linkedin</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://pinterest.com">Pinterest</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a> <br />
                </li>
                <li class="under" style="margin-left: 30%;">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">About</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">Policies</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">Careers</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://pinterest.com">Press</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://youtube.com">Developers</a> <br />
                </li>
                <li class="under" style="margin-left: 50%;">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">Detroit</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">London</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">Florida</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://pinterest.com">Las Vegas</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://youtube.com">California</a> <br />
                </li>
                <li class="under" style="margin-left: 70%;">
                    Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris <br />
                    condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet <br />
                    risus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus <br />
                    posuere velit aliquet. Praesent commodo cursus magna, <br />
                    vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Sed posuere consectetur <br />
                </li>
            </ul>

            <img id="fterblk" src="fterblk.png" alt="black" />
            <p style="text-align: center center; position: absolute; top: 285%; left: 50%;color:white;  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Copyright 2015-2016 @renkj</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
    html{
    min-height: 100%; margin: 0;
}
body { min-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 5.3%;
}
.header {
    background-image:url(bghero.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    height: 200%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 70%;
    src: url('Montserrat-bold.otf') format('truetype');
}
#circle{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 4%;
}
#big{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 900%;
    top: 40%;
    color: white;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;

}
#sml{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 150%;
    top: 73%;
    color: white;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
}
#smpline{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    height: 0.2%;
    width: 90%;
}
#ham{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    right:0%;
}
#src{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.8%;
    right:0%;
}
#menu1{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    right: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
#menu2{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu3{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}

#lowerfoto{
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
}
#fteweit{
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#fterblk{
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Montserrat;
   position: absolute;
   top: 245%;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
.head li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 248%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}
.under li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    top: 255%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-style: none;
    color: #565656;
}
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

so the thing is, whenever I change the 
to  (which represents html5) the background picture isn't working... what should I do?
I searched all over the internet for information but I didnt find anything to help me, and when I did find it didnt work. :/
I cant figure out what's wrong with that...

Comment: Well for starters your `DOCTYPE` is wrong. It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` - see the W3 standard https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: when I use <!DOCTYPE html> instead of <!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM> the background is not working, which is the problem I am having.

Comment: Be more specific and concise. Don't share all of your code, just the part which seems to be broken. Which background are you referring to?

Comment: the background image, as used in the css:     background-image:url(bghero.png); (the picutre is bghero.png)

Comment: So the one in the `.header` class?

Comment: yes. the one in the .header

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example to show you background-image working in action :

You need to set a height value for your `header` DIV.

```css
.header {
    background-image:url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    height: 200px; // you had this set to 200%
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 70%;
    src: url('Montserrat-bold.otf') format('truetype');
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: okay, but now I have white space in the top and white space in the bottom and the other positions are screwed.

Comment: Well that's outside the scope of this question. You wanted to know why the `background-image` wasn't visible. I answered your question, so please accept this answer.

Comment: yes but all the other things now aren't working. your answer is right but not completely right.

Comment: But my solution didn't cause your problems. You have brittle code, and you can't expect somebody to debug your whole web page. Stackoverflow is designed for short specific answers, not `Fix my whole web page - help!`

Comment: but It did work before the change from <!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM> to <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: Do you have a live demo of your site, so I can see?

Comment: uhm probably not but I can search for something like that or you can download it from my github: https://github.com/renkj137/WEBDESIGN

Comment: Why you need `<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Comment: I don't but when I do use <!DOCTYPE HTML> it doesn't work properly.